# Insertion of subscript text in a column of a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert H2O into a column where the "2" should be stored as a subscript in PostgreSQL table (`H₂O`).
What will be insert query for this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stored as subscript", what is *H2O*, what your table looks like, etc...

Comment: `insert into ... values ('H₂O')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am getting H<sub>2</sub>O as an output.

Comment: @eurotrash : H2O is chemical formula of water.

Comment: @melpomene : I have a data in XML as H2O. I have to convert it into H₂O and store it in posgresql table.

Comment: @Prakash OK, then do that. You have my permission.

Answer (score 1):

If your input:

- is always a chemical formula,
- uses mostly (but incorrectly) normal numbers, and
- normal numbers can't occur anyway in them, just [subscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts),

then you can use the `translate()` function upon insertion:

```
translate(formula, '0123456789', '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉')
```

http://rextester.com/XUDCXA71407

If you have other characters too, which you want to replace with its counterparts, then you'll need a slightly advanced expression:

```
regexp_replace(translate(regexp_replace(formula, '<.*?>', '', 'g'), '0123456789-', '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₋'), 'x(e[urs]|[^e]|$)', 'ₓ\1', 'ig')
```

http://rextester.com/SCHLWJ33436

*Notes*:

- the expression above just adds `-` and `X`, however
- it assumes `-` always needed to be in subscript
- `X` is only needed to be in subscript, where

  - it does not followed by `e` (so it will leave `Xe` as is)
  - if it is followed by `e`, the string must be continued with either `u`, `r`, or `s` (so `??ₓEu`, `??ₓEr` and `??ₓEs` will be generated)
- as you can see, this depends on the actual periodic table, so I would consider this kind of solution very fragile, but there are no other solutions in SQL for your problem
- also, the unicode subscript set is very limited. you may be able to add a few more pairs to this conversion, but you should consider storing the original formula instead.

Or, if you can guarantee that every subscript `x` will be in lower case (this way, it cannot collide with `Xe`), then:

```
translate(regexp_replace(formula, '<.*?>', '', 'g'), '0123456789-x', '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₋ₓ')
```

http://rextester.com/WPRDO99076

Comment: I have XML structure like <mod>Sr<sub>1-x</sub>
Ba<sub>x</sub>Nb
<sub>2</sub>O
<sub>6</sub>
</mod>    I have to store it as Sr(1-x)Ba(x)Nb(2)O(6) in table. character inside () should be store as subscript.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very useful solution.